# Simultaneous blinking LEDs, with separate and inconsistent patterns

Tags: c, random, arduino, delay, led

I'm trying to run two "Blink"-esque functions simultaneously.

I've found some code elsewhere that lets me do that and modified it! Great.

However, what I am trying to do is have one LED turn on and off every 1000ms as per usual, but have the other blink in an odd pattern, like ON for 3000ms, OFF for 100ms, ON for 100ms, OFF for 200ms then loop back.

To make this happen I tried adding a random function to the code I found but I don't like how it looks. It looks like a blinking LED with interference or something, like on a radio transmitter or whatever. I'm trying to replicate an old flickering lightbulb, meaning it always has to be ON for longer than it is off, Essentially it needs to be ON/HIGH for a "longer" period of time and then interrupted by several short flashes of ON and OFF

So I'm looking for help in how I can orchestrate the 2nd LED to turn on and off in a more specific series of flickers.

Here's the code I'm using so far:

```
/* Blink Multiple LEDs without Delay
*
* Turns on and off several light emitting diode(LED) connected to a digital
* pin, without using the delay() function.  This means that other code
* can run at the same time without being interrupted by the LED code.
*/
int led1 = 13;                // LED connected to digital pin 13
int led2 = 12;
int value1 = LOW;                // previous value of the LED
int value2 = HIGH;                // previous value of the LED
long time1 = millis();
long time2 = millis();

long interval1 = 1000;           // interval at which to blink (milliseconds)

void setup()
{
 Serial.begin(9600);
 randomSeed(analogRead(0));
 pinMode(led1, OUTPUT);      // sets the digital pin as output
 pinMode(led2, OUTPUT);
}

void loop()
{
 unsigned long m = millis();

 if (m - time1 > interval1){
   time1 = m;

   if (value1 == LOW)
     value1 = HIGH;
   else
     value1 = LOW;

   digitalWrite(led1, value1);
 }

long interval2 = random(100,1500);

 if (m - time2 > interval2){
   time2 = m;

   if (value2 == LOW)
     value2 = HIGH;
   else
     value2 = LOW;

   digitalWrite(led2, value2);
 }

   Serial.println(interval2);
}
```

Comment: I started writing a solution to this when you first posted it but I didn't have the arduino IDE nor an actual arduino so I began writing it in plain C. Eventually fell asleep :D Anyway, make a function called `flicker()` or similar that turns the LED on and off in a for loop with a very short, random delay in between. Then call this function at random every 15-60 seconds or so. I think that'll give the impression of a near-death light bulb

Comment: Thanks for the idea, I'll play around but doesn't DELAY pause everything? And therefore will pause the 2nd LED that needs a constant rhythm of ON/OFF every 1000ms?

Comment: Yeah, I think `delay` blocks execution but you can use time comparison instead of `delay`s like you're doing in `if (m - time1 > interval1){ ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will always take less than a second to run so you can get back to your main loop and ensure that you don't miss the 1 second on/off for the other LED:

```
void flicker(){
    boolean state = false;
    int r = random(20, 175);
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        digitalWrite(led2, state);
        state = !state;
        delay(r);
        r = random(20, 175);
    }
    digitalWrite(led2, HIGH);
}
```

Btw. I'm replacing this toggle code:

```
if (value2 == LOW)
  value2 = HIGH;
else
  value2 = LOW;

digitalWrite(led2, value2);
```

with this:

```
state = !state;
digitalWrite(led2, state);
```

Now, call `flicker()` at random intervals; maybe every 15-45 seconds or whatever you find appropriate/realistic.

Comment: Im sorry i dont want to be annoying but could you possibly post the code in full? I'm trying to implement what you have here but am getting a slew of different error messages. I musnt understand on a fundamental level here....

Comment: @ConnorCrawford I'm just writing this "free-hand" without access to an arduino so the errors might be my fault. But the stuff that's not included in the answer is only the setup and main functions that you already have and then the time comparison in the main loop that calls `flicker()` at a random interval of maybe 15-45 seconds. Which errors are you getting?

Comment: thanks again. Im getting "void value not ignored as it ought to be" when I try to call the flicker(); function now. I was also getting 'state not declared in this scope' which im not sure if it will crop back up after I fix the first error. maybe i dont know how to call the function properly, let alone every 15-45 seconds. _`if (m - time2 > interval2){
    time2 = m;
    int onoff;    
    onoff = flicker(); 
    
    state = !state;
    digitalWrite(led2, state);

}`_

Comment: Remove all of this `int onoff; onoff = flicker(); state = !state; digitalWrite(led2, state);` and replace it with `flicker();` and nothing else. You just need to *call* the function called `flicker()`, not assign its return value to a variable (which won't work since it has none; that's what `void` means)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
void setup()
{
 Serial.begin(9600);
 randomSeed(analogRead(0));
 pinMode(led1, OUTPUT);      // sets the digital pin as output
 pinMode(led2, OUTPUT);
}

long interval2 = random(100,1500);

void loop()
{
 unsigned long m = millis();

 if (m - time1 > interval1){
   time1 = m;

   if (value1 == LOW)
     value1 = HIGH;
   else
     value1 = LOW;

   digitalWrite(led1, value1);
 }

 if (m - time2 > interval2){
   time2 = m;

   if (value2 == LOW) {
     value2 = HIGH;
     interval2 = random(100, 1500);
   } else {
     value2 = LOW;
     interval2 = random(100, 200);
   }

   digitalWrite(led2, value2);
 }
```

Comment: I see what you are driving at, and it is even closer than before, thank you. However it still looks to me like simply a blinking light, fairly binary on/off-y. I'm wondering if theres a way to cause it to go back to HIGH after LOW but a "new  separate HIGH" that has a smaller random range....

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand what you mean by "new separate HIGH", could you explain more elaborately what you want (not in programming terms, just what result you want)?

Comment: yes, sorry - Your edit to the code allows for the LED to stay  ON/HIGH for a random period between 100 and 1500. then OFF/LOW between 100 and 200. I want the LED to be ON/HIGH for a period between 1000 and 1500, then OFF/LOW for a period between 100 and 200 then ON/HIGH again but only for a period between 100 and 200, then OFF/LOW yet again for a period between 100 and 200. At this point it could cycle back and repeat, but more control/ additional HIGHS and LOWS would be ideal. Essentially it needs to be on for a "long" period of time and then interrupted by several short flashes of ON and OFF